# ReactJs setState not re-render

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I try setState in reactjs. the value change but the view not re-render

this my event click on button and upload file set it to state. (the logic storage is good. everything is good. the problem state not trigger re-render.

```
handleRear = async(e) => {
    const image = document.getElementById("foto_rear").files[0]
    const storageRef = storage().ref('registrasi/driver/' + uuidv1().toString() + '.jpg')
    const uploadTask = await storageRef.put(image)
    const getURL = await uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL()
    console.log(getURL)
    firestore().collection('registrasi').doc(this.props.data.id)
      .set({
        foto: {
          foto_rear: {
            downloadURL: getURL.toString()
          }
        }
      }, {merge: true})
      console.log('Done')
    this.setState({urlFotoRear: <div>{getURL}</div>},
    () => console.log(this.state.urlFotoRear))
  };
```

this render function

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item xs={3}>
            <div>
              {this.state.urlFotoRear}
            </div>
            <div>
              <input id="foto_rear" name="foto_rear" type="file" onChange={this.handleRear} value=""/>
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

this default state

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      urlFotoRear: <div>{this.props.data.foto.foto_rear.downloadURL}</div>,
    }
}
```

[image: Console Log]

Comment: Do you have a `this.handleRear = this.handleRear.bind(this)` in your constructor? If not, add it.

Comment: Please provide complete code.

Comment: no, there is no handleRear in my constructor.

Comment: You cant directly mutate the state, thats what setState is for

Comment: @SpeedOfRound i already update and delete that. but still no luck.

this.setState({urlFotoRear: <div>{this.props.data.foto.foto_rear.downloadURL}</div>},
    () => console.log(this.state.urlFotoRear))

thats state i mean

Comment: @Kevin.a this.setState({urlFotoRear: <div>{this.props.data.foto.foto_rear.downloadURL}</div>},
    () => console.log(this.state.urlFotoRear))

Comment: If your default state is equal to what you want it changed into , it wont re-render

Comment: Can you show us either the complete code, or what you're getting in console?

Comment: @Kevin.a i already change it. and still not change. but when i close the Dialog and open it again its load last value so thats mean firestore logic work. but not the state

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      urlFotoRear: <div>{this.props.data.foto.foto_rear.downloadURL}</div>,
    }
this.handleRear = this.handleRear.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: It'd be very useful If you'd have provided some explanation about this code.

Comment: It is what i commented above and should be the solution. handleRear is called during an event and has no access to `this` unless you bind it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your setState actually triggers a re-render, you just don't see anything new, because the URL stays the same.

The state you're setting in `handleRear` looks the same as the one in your `constructor`.

```
this.state  = {urlFotoRear: <div>{this.props.data.foto.foto_rear.downloadURL}</div>}
... compare with ...
this.setState({urlFotoRear: <div>{this.props.data.foto.foto_rear.downloadURL}</div>})
```

Did you mean to write this in your `handleRear()` method?

```
  handleRear = async(e) => {
    const image = document.getElementById("foto_rear").files[0]
    const storageRef = storage().ref('registrasi/driver/' + uuidv1().toString() + '.jpg')
    const uploadTask = await storageRef.put(image)
    const getURL = await uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL()
    /// ...
    this.setState(
      {urlFotoRear: <div>{getURL}</div>},
      () => console.log(this.state.urlFotoRear)
    )
  };
```

Comment: check the update. i already updated with getURL but in console. the div (in state change) but on screen still use old one

Comment: but when i close the dialog. and open it again. its use new value. (not reload)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't see no further errors in the snippets of code you provided. Maybe if you shared the code of the entire component, we'll be able to find something.

Comment: Yeah i found it. its because the constructor call twice idk why.